# Cannot open SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I downloaded SQL Server 2016 Express and Visual Studio 2015.

I get this message when I try to open SQL Server is my Visual Studio program.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

My code is

```
//  _ConnectionString = "Server = ARKY/SQLExpress; Database = Tracker; User Id = Track;Password =Track;Trusted_Connection=True;";
_ConnectionString = "Server = ARKY/SQLExpress; Database = Tracker;Trusted_Connection=True;Connect Timeout=10";

SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString);

try
{
    myConnection.Open();
    return "";
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return e.Message + " " + _ConnectionString;
}
```

I tried my different connection strings. This is one example.

`ARKY` is the name of my computer and `SQLEXPRESS` is my named instance.

[image]

See the screen shot of my SQL Server database. I will appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Couple possibilities: 1) The spacing around the "Server = ARKY/SQLExpress" is off.  I'm not sure if it comes into play but might it be picking up the space between = and ARKY as a valid character?  2) Your instance of SQL Server isn't configured to receive remote connections.  3) If your connection is travelling through a network, it's possible that firewalls/security is preventing a connection.  Any of those 3 sound like they could be causing you some trouble?

Comment: An oldy but a goody - do a [UDL test](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2007/12/31/basics-first-udl-test/). Do that and copy the results into your connection string in your c# code. If you cant get that to work (the udl test) then its a problem communicating with sql server and nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
_ConnectionString = @"Data Source=ARKY\SQLExpress;InitialCatalog=Tracker;Trusted_Connection=True;Connection Timeout=10";
```

You need a backslash rather than a front slash in your server name, and several parameters are misnamed.

In general, you can open "Server Explorer" in VS, add a data connection to your server there, then click on the data connection and look for the connection string in the properties window.  You can cut and paste from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one

```
   _ConnectionString = "Data Source=ARKY/SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Tracker;Trusted_Connection=True;Connect Timeout=10";
```

Comment: This is the string that worked. I found this by going to Tools connect to database. Data Source=ARKY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Tracker;Integrated Security=True

Answer (score 0):

`_ConnectionString = "Server = ARKY\\SQLExpress; Database = Tracker;Trusted_Connection=True;Connect Timeout=10";`

Check your connection string as well
From FIX : ERROR : Could not open a connection to SQL Server:
Check if your SQL server services is up and running properly:

Go to All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2016 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Services
Check to make sure SQL Server service status is Running.
In addition, ensure that your remote server is in the same network. Run sqlcmd -L to ascertain if your server is included in your network list.
Enable TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration

When two or more SQL Servers are connected across network they do all communication using TCP/IP. The default port of SQL Server installation is 1433. This port can be changed through SQL Server Configuration Manager. TCP/IP should be enabled for SQL Server to be connected.

Go to All Programs >> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 >> Configuration Tools >> SQL Server Configuration Manager >> Select TCP/IP
Right Click on TCP/IP >> Click on Enable
You must restart SQL Server Services for all the changes to take effect. Right click and go to menu properties to select location where default port of SQL Server can be changed.